# A and B, B raises exception only if A is False - conisdered a good style?

Tags: coding-style, exception

Canonical example:

```
while foo.hasBar() && foo.getBar() != spam
{
     do lots of stuff
}
```

foo.getBar() will raise an exception if it has no bar. However, it is guaranteed that this expression will not be evaluated unless foo has a bar. Is that considered a good programming style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in a language that guarantees that kind of evaluation for a boolean and (this is very common, and is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)), then yes, that's of course fine to rely on.

On the other hand, needlessly repeating the `foo.hasBar()` test in the loop seems very clumsy to me.